# GUI for view data in aerospike

Tags: aerospike

I want to view data in aerospike, but I can't find any GUI tool. 
Console applications like *aql* is uncomfortable.
Does it exist such GUI tools?

Answer (score 3):

**Current answer:** 2021 called and wanted me to change the voicemail. There's an Aerospike supported minimalist JDBC driver at https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-jdbc

It differs from the community one in that it only gives you functionality that exists in the database, without any client-side workarounds. As a result it's small, fast, and gets expanded SQL capabilities every time there's new native functionality to use.
See the examples page for the type of [SQL queries](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-jdbc/blob/main/docs/examples.md) you can execute with it.

**Previous answer:** the easiest (at the moment) would be to use [alexradzin/aerospike-jdbc-driver](https://github.com/alexradzin/aerospike-jdbc-driver) together with something like [SQquirreL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) or [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/).

Alex published a 4 part [Introduction to the Aerospike JDBC driver](https://dev.to/alexradzin/introduction-to-the-aerospike-jdbc-driver-51m4) on DEV.

**Orignal answer:**
There's an experimental data browser for Aerospike project called [Clairvoyance](https://github.com/rashidmayes/Clairvoyance).

Comment: Looks like it's too experimental. I tried to start, but without success. There is no any docs there.

Comment: I know that it's in use already, and you did leave an issue on the repo. You know, open source projects need community help. Anyway, AQL should work till then, or till another data browser arrives.

Comment: I tested Clairvoyance, also I added pull request to Clairvoyance.
Looks like it's too simple. It's like aql. 
I want to find something more "smart" and easy for non programmers.

Comment: You can use https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-jdbc with DBeaver, JetBrain's DataGrid, SQuirrel or any other JDBC based data browser. The README is pretty good but you can also check out this blog post about Aerospike's JDBC Driver: https://medium.com/aerospike-developer-blog/introducing-aerospike-jdbc-driver-fe46d9fc3b4d

Answer (score 1):

For older versions you can use [onlyAQL](https://github.com/jain-neeeraj/OnlyAQL).

The link to the compiled version is broken, but I was able to compile and run it with `java -jar target\onlyAQL-0.0.1.jar` by adding 2 plugins to `pom.xml` and running `mvn package`.

To do that add the following to `pom.xml`:

```xml
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                <mainClass>guiComponents.onlyAQL</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>copy-dependencies</id>
              <phase>prepare-package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>
                  ${project.build.directory}/lib
                </outputDirectory>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
```